# How can I receive a new verification email?

Tags: pokemon-go

I signed up with Pokémon Trainer Club on Pokémon Go, but after playing for 3 days and reaching level 18, I could no longer log in.

I think the problem is that when I signed up, I didn't check my email, where I think I was supposed to receive a verification message. I have tried to send a new verification email, but nothing shows up in my inbox. Therefore, I think I've signed up with an email address that I've forgotten.

In short: how can I change the address that the Trainer Club sends their verification email to?

Comment: 3 days lvl 18 ? Did you happen to glitch or cheat by any chance ?

Comment: Nope just played alot, didnt use any money either was just lucky with lures put out by others

Answer (score 1):

There is a page to request resending of your activation code which can be found here:

https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/activated

If you are unsure of your username you can try this link:

https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-username

There doesn't seem to be much that can help you if you have forgotten what email address you used. I would imagine few people have so many email addresses that they can't just check all accounts.

To help to locate emails from them the address used to send the emails is noreply@pokemon.com so you can try searching all your email accounts for emails from them.

Also as extra information I quote the text you get after registering:

> Thank you for creating a Pokémon Trainer Club account. We have sent
> you an email to verify your account. When you verify your account,
> you'll get 25 Trainer Tokens as a reward! You have two days to use
> your Pokémon Trainer Club account without verifying your account.
> After that time, you'll have to verify your account before you can
> sign in again.

So next time when something tells you that you need to verify do it immediately! :)

As a final note if you are having problems because you put the wrong email address in or something similar to that then their web page suggests:

> Pokémon Trainer Club Account Setup and Log-In Problems:
>
> If you are
> having trouble with account creation, or are having issues logging
> into your account, you can email us directly at: techhelp@pokemon.com.

Comment: Doesnt help me login

Comment: The first link was to request a new activation code which is what you asked for. Did you not get an email or did you get it and still can't log in or something else?

Comment: I havent gotten any emails, thats the whole point

Comment: @DanielAakhus: I'm a little confused as to what you are after. You asked how to get it to resend a verfication email which the first link I gave you will do. If the problem is that you don't know what email address you used to sign up or that you made a mistake in it so it didn't actually go to your account then you could try emailing them. I've added a further bit to my answer about contacting their support team. If you don't have control over the email address that is registered under though I will be very surprised if they could help you. On the plus side its only three days you've lost...

Comment: Well 3 days = lvl 18 and i am sorry for being so unclear, but i will contsnct their support team, thx will update their respond

Comment: The thing is, i cant ask them questions becuase i cant login becuas i cant verify

Comment: Why do you need to log in to be able to email them?

Comment: I dont know why, but their internet site has that requirement. I can of course send the question from some other device, but then i woild need to create snother account

Comment: There is a support thing that requires logging in but email is nothing to do with their website. Anybody can email them with a problem. The email address is explicitly stated as being for people having issues logging into their account so requiring you to be logged in while technically impossible (your email client can't tell if you are logged into an arbitrary website) is also completely unnecessary. Just email them and explain your problem.